# Setup Project and script folder moving

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2008, setup-project

I include a javascript include folder in the root directory of my setup project in the Application Folder.  I tried to move the javascript include file under the Javascript folder and I now get:

> Unable to find source file 'C:\Documents and Settings\support\My
>   Documents\Projects\u2server\wwwroot\ckeditor\ckeditor_basic_source.js'
>   for file 'ckeditor_basic_source.js', located in
>   '[TARGETDIR]\wwwroot\Scripts\ckeditor', the file may be absent or
>   locked.

I can delete the the directory and then add the files one by one but their are over 200 files in that include directory.  Is their an easy way to move a folder in the application folder of the file system view of a setup program?

Answer (score 0):

When moving files on disk you also need to update your setup project. The simplest approach is to remove the entire folder in your setup project File System Editor and add it again in the correct location. This way it will use the correct paths.